# Open covering regarding limits

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am studying for an exam and I am almost grasping compactness. However, some examples are still unclear. E.g. for $A = (a, b)$ with $a < b$ and $a, b \in  \mathbb{R}$.
How can $(a, b) \subseteq \cup _{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in (a, b − \frac{1}{k})$, making this an open covering. Even though $\frac{1}{k} \ge 0$ for $k\ge\infty$, how is this set still covering $(a,b)$ when $b -\frac{1}{k}$ is smaller than $b$? I hope you can make this clear for me, thanks!

Comment: $b-1/k$ is smaller than $b$ but it is arbitrarily close to $b$ from the left as $k$ increases; note that it is an open cover for the open interval $(a,b)$ which doesn't include the endpoints $a,b$

Comment: For any $c\in (a,b)$, it is contained in $(a,b-1/k)$ for all integers $k\gt 1/(b-c)$

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in(a,b)$ then $a<x<b$. Consider $b-x>0$. There is some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}<b-x$, so $x<b-\frac{1}{n_0}$. Then $x\in(a,b-\frac{1}{n_0})$, and since $(a,b-\frac{1}{n_0})\subset\cup_{k\in\Bbb N}(a,b-\frac{1}{k})$, we have $x\in\cup_{k\in\Bbb N}(a,b-\frac{1}{k})$. Therefore $(a,b)\subseteq\cup_{k\in\Bbb N}(a,b-\frac{1}{k})$.

In fact it is an equality, since $(a,b-\frac{1}{k})\subset(a,b)\quad \forall k\in\Bbb N\Rightarrow\cup_{k\in\Bbb N}(a,b-\frac{1}{k})\subseteq (a,b)$

Comment: $\left(a,b-\frac1{n_0}\right)$ is a **subset** of $\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(a,b-\frac1k\right)$, not an **element** of it; it’s an element of $\left\{\left(a,b-\frac1k\right):k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.

Comment: You're right. It was a slip, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

"how is this set still covering (a,b) when b−1k is smaller than b"

Because $b$ is *not* in $(a,b)$. so it never needs to be covered.

*Every* point in $(a,b)$ is *also* smaller than $b$ and for every point $x \in (a,b)$ we have $x<b$ and there is some $b-\frac 1k$ so that $x < b-\frac 1k < b$.

Notice: because $b$ is *not* in $(a,b)$ but $b$ *is* a limit point of $(a,b)$ that that is *why* $(a,b)$ is not closed.  And therefore $(a,b)$ is not compact.  If we consider $[a,b]$ so $b$ *was* in $[a,b]$ then those would not be an open cove because $b$ is *not* covered.  To have an open cover we'd need an open set with $b$ and that set (because it is open) would have to have so points *beyond* $b$ as well.  And that one open set because it goes "over" covers an infinite number of points.  This is why (in $\mathbb R$) compact sets must be closed.